# How to obtain the distance (dissimilarity) between two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Supposed that two entities ($A$, and $B$) with several features, and we wrap the features into two vectors, namely

$v_A=(area_A, distance_A, angle_A,...)$,

$v_B=(area_B, distance_B, angle_B,...)$.

The features in the the vectors are with different units. How can I obtain the distance(dissimularity) between two vectors. For instance,

$v_A=(2 meter^2, 3 meters, 50 degrees,...)$,

$v_B=(1.5 meter^2, 4 meters, 40 degrees,...)$.

Can I calculate the distance by

$d_{AB}=\sqrt{(2-1.5)^2+(3-4)^2+(50-40)^2+...}$ ?

I need to normalize them? And how to do it?

Comment: No, your $d_{AB}$ can't work. Forget about normalizing; you're trying to add "apples" and "oranges" inside the radical. And that won't work to begin with.

Comment: @John Forkosh, even though they are the apples and oranges, I think we can still compare their simularity (or dissimularity), such as the shape (almost sphere), size (about 10cm in diameter, very similar to each other)...

Comment: Does a distance change if you use cm instead of meters?

Comment: Unless you have fixed parameters of your system that let you normalize away all the units, there will be no canonical measure of dissimilarity. It's as the other commenters have said: apples and oranges. That said, you can arbitrarily cook up a measure by weighting things in whichever way you find appropriate (this will suffice for many applications -- at the level of topology, all norms on finite dimensional euclidean space are equivalent). The only problem is that it will be sensitive to your choice of units, which means the result will have no physical interpretation.

Comment: @Charles Hudgins, thanks for your comment. I think I understand what you mean.